# ValidationError: Required path Mongoose NestJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a service named "problems", which that handle CRUD operations.
Now, in the service, when I want save a document, I have this error:

```
ValidationError: Problem validation failed: creator: Path `creator` is required., description: Path `description` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
```

This is my schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument } from 'mongoose';

export type ProblemDocument = HydratedDocument<Problem>;

@Schema()
export class Problem {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  title: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  description: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  creator: string;

  @Prop()
  ideas: string[];

  @Prop()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Prop()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @Prop()
  deletedAt: Date;
}

export const ProblemSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Problem);
```

create method in problems service:

```
async create(createProblemDto: CreateProblemDto): Promise<any> {
    try {
      console.log(createProblemDto);
      const problem = new this.ProblemModel({ createProblemDto });
      return problem.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

createProblem DTO:

```
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateProblemDto {
  @IsString({ message: 'Title must be a string' })
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Title is required' })
  title: string;

  @IsString({ message: 'Description must be a string' })
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Description is required' })
  description: string;

  @IsString({ message: 'Creator must be a string' })
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Creator is required' })
  creator: string;
}
```

This is my request:

POST http://localhost:3000/problems
Content-Type: application/json

{
"title": "hello",
"description": "world",
"creator": "john_doe"
}

and this is logs in console:

```
{
  createProblemDto: { title: 'hello', description: 'world', creator: 'john_doe' }
}
[Nest] 17591  - 01/02/2024, 6:00:27 PM   ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] Problem validation failed: creator: Path `creator` is required., description: Path `description` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
ValidationError: Problem validation failed: creator: Path `creator` is required., description: Path `description` is required., title: Path `title` is required.
    at model.Document.invalidate (/home/arta/project/vsCode/nestjs/devProblem/problems/node_modules/.pnpm/mongoose@8.0.3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3187:32)
    at /home/arta/project/vsCode/nestjs/devProblem/problems/node_modules/.pnpm/mongoose@8.0.3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2980:17
    at /home/arta/project/vsCode/nestjs/devProblem/problems/node_modules/.pnpm/mongoose@8.0.3/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1368:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing, to `ProblemModel` constructor, what it expects in the service.

Try changing your service method to the following:

```
async create(createProblemDto: CreateProblemDto): Promise<any> {
      try {
          console.log(createProblemDto);
          const problem = new this.ProblemModel({ ...createProblemDto });
          return problem.save();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
 }
```

Alternatively, you can pass the parameter as is without using the spread operator.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.
I used the spread operator but I still have the same error as before.

Comment: Did you try clearing cache after spreading the dto-object?